# Tomcat 7 + MyFaces 2.1 : java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, tomcat, myfaces

I'm setting up a simple application using Tomcat 7 and MyFaces 2.1.
I create the app, create a simple index.xhtml, deploy it and when I visit it on the browser I get the exception.
I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856248/nosuchalgorithmexception-algorithm-hmacsha1-not-available) in which a solution was given, but it didn't work for me because I already have the settings suggested in the answer.

This is the stack trace i get:

```
19-lug-2011 9.38.45 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacSHA1 not available
    at javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.encrypt(StateUtils.java:306)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.construct(StateUtils.java:239)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseStateManager.writeViewStateField(HtmlResponseStateManager.java:138)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseStateManager.writeState(HtmlResponseStateManager.java:116)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:308)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.flushBufferToWriter(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:285)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.renderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:210)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:281)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:745)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:65)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
19-lug-2011 9.38.45 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/mcconsole] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 7

4: <html>
5: <head> </head>
6: <body>
7: <jsp:forward page="/testIndex.jsf" />
8: </body>
9: </html>
```

Thank  you very much for any kind of help.

SOLUTION:

I got to the solution:
I uninstalled ***Java SE 6 Update 26***, installed ***JDK 6 Update 26 with Java EE***, changed Eclipse and Tomcat properties to use new JDK (under Glassfish folder) and now it seems to be correctly working.
I got Glassfish installed, too, whether I don't need it, but it's not a problem.

Comment: For clarity, it's a server/JVM environment problem, not a JSF/MyFaces problem. Updating/reinstalling/replacing the server and/or JVM might help somewhat.

Comment: I reinstalled both JVM (JDK 1.6u26) and Server (Tomcat 7.0.16) but the problem persists.  Any other idea?   Thank you!

Comment: What operating system platform are you running?

Comment: They are running on Windows 7 :-(

Comment: I got to the solution:
I uninstalled ***Java SE 6 Update 26***, installed ***JDK 6 Update 26 with Java EE***, changed Eclipse and Tomcat properties to use new JDK (under Glassfish folder) and now it seems to be correctly working.
I got Glassfish installed, too, whether I don't need it, but it's not a problem.

Comment: Thus.. Just Java SE JDK wasn't sufficient to solve the problem? You really needed the whole Java EE pack on top of it..?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help directly (never had problems with it). I would use the Archetype for generating the setup or I would write a mail to the mailing list.

Comment: Note that the OP has posted the final answer at bottom of the question and in question's comments.