# Cannot set up certs for trusted CAs for com.adobe.adept.client.XMLUtil

Tags: java, adobe, policy, jce

I have the next exception::

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
     at javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
     at com.adobe.adept.client.XMLUtil.createHMAC(XMLUtil.java:815)
     at com.adobe.adept.client.XMLUtil.hmac(XMLUtil.java:788)
     at com.adobe.adept.upload.UploadTest.makeContent(UploadTest.java:1454)
     at com.adobe.adept.upload.UploadTest.<init>(UploadTest.java:1769)
     at com.adobe.adept.upload.UploadTest.main(UploadTest.java:1806) Caused
 by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot set up certs for trusted CAs
     at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.<clinit>(DashoA13*..)
     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot locate policy or framework files!
     at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.i(DashoA13*..)
     at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.g(DashoA13*..)
     at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b$1.run(DashoA13*..)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     ... 7 more
```

it is occurring on line:

```
 Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
```

I tried next solutions:
 - [NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacSHA1 not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856248/nosuchalgorithmexception-algorithm-hmacsha1-not-available) - my local java.security file in actual state
 - https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=316839

may be someone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

fixed. problem was in my code, I have unusable:

```
System.setProperties(props);
```

where props - properites of config file