# How do I remove the Java crypto restrictions?

Tags: java, cryptography, jce

I am doing some crypto for my homework. The program doesn't show any errors while compiling. However when I run the program I get an exception - `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException`. I think this is due to the crypto restrictions. I have downloded and imported Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 6 (but I am not sure whether the these libraries actually do the crypto). I couldn't find any Sun JCE jar which I've seen imported in some example programs that use crypto ( like `import com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE`).

Can anyone provide any directions as to how to run my code without exceptions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2856248/139010

Comment: See this question for a runtime solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435227/java-patching-client-side-security-policy-from-applet-for-aes256/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download [these files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html) and follow the installation instruction in jce\README.txt