# What Elliptical Curve support exists in .NET? Can I define my own curves, or replicate SEC standards?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, logarithm, bitcoin

What are the limitations of the Microsoft Elliptical Curve support in .NET?  I'm referring only to what's possible with the System.Cryptography namespace.

With that namespace, can I implement custom curves, or am I limited to a distinct subset which is hard coded in the framework?

One curve I'm particularly interested in is secp256k1, though I don't want to limit myself to that.

Why am I not using Bouncy Castle, and only focused on Microsoft?  The reason is because the Microsoft implementations of the Hash functions are many times faster than Bouncy Castle, and so therefore I think the custom Elliptical Curve based encryption.

I don't mind if I need to update the registry or an ini file to add support for additional curves, or build low-level classes; I just want to see what the possibilities and limitations are.

Comment: Does this help?: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/which-programming-languages-support-secp256k1

Comment: @weston I've seen that link, and the C# code it refers to.  No, it only shows the Bouncy Castle implementation... I'm interested in using Microsoft-only libraries to implement EC

Comment: @makerofthings7: If MS-only stuff could really do it worth a damn, why would it be so hard to find examples that *don't* revolve around a third-party library?

Comment: @cHao Because existing examples involving third party libraries don't always tell the whole story. Case in point: The default cryptography provider in Java limits AES key size to 128 bits. The straightforward answer for those who need 256-bit keys is to use the Bouncy Castle provider. Installing an extra 2MB library that duplicates standard functionality is suboptimal for many reasons, yet no-one seems to have a better solution. Eventually, after months of (on-and-off) research, I managed to solve the issue without involving third party libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18437016/2424896

Answer (score 3):

The only supported curves by .NET are (and have long been) the P-xxx curves defined by NIST in Suite B. Any other curves are not supported out of the box. You have defined a specific non-NIST non-prime curve (a Koblitz curve) that is therefore not supported by CNG.

To be more precise, [CNG only supports the following domain parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for ECDSA and ECDH keys. Those parameters are only supported when they are used for "named curves" too:

> P-256, P-384, P-521

Note: as I don't have an NDA or similar with Microsoft, I cannot check if these values are hard coded, but I would consider that very likely.

Comment: all the recommended curves are 'backdoored' by NSA. Do not use them.

Comment: @RedHotScalability Don't spread FUD. Nobody found a way to see how the current parameters can be exploited. The random number generation is somewhat suspicious, so you are better off using a [safe curve](http://safecurves.cr.yp.to). The only thing that we are pretty sure of to be backdoor'ed is the Dual EC *random number generator*.