# Unable to calculate a request signature: Algorithm HmacSHA1 not available

Tags: java, algorithm, maven, amazon-s3, javafx

- I develop one javaFx application.
- which upload the files on amazon s3 server.
- The application work fine when the executable jar of the application is made.
- But when the native packaging of the application is done the .msi file is
  created and after installing .msi the application started correctly
  but at the time of uploading file on s3 the "Unable to calculate a request signature: Algorithm HmacSHA1 not available"  error occur in log file.
- The creation of the jar and native application is done by the com.zenjava maven plugin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacSHA1 not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856248/nosuchalgorithmexception-algorithm-hmacsha1-not-available)

Comment: i got the solution.when the jre is created in packaging it does not contain "ext" folder which is available in regular jre which contain jars which are required for performing task related with java.sequrity package.so after putting "ext" folder in native bundle jar problem is solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution.when the jre is created in packaging it does not contain "ext" folder which is available in regular jre which contain jars which are required for performing task related with java.sequrity package.so after putting "ext" folder in native bundle jar problem is solve